# How to infer type of a map while restricting the values to a known set?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to create a map from a set of string keys to a set of specific strings:

```
type Datum = { LOCATION: string, GENDER: number }

export const fieldKeys: Record<strings, keyof Datum> = {
  country: "LOCATION",
  gender: "GENDER"
};
```

so that later I can index an object of type `Datum` through one of the field keys:

```
const d: Datum = { /* … */ }
const country = d[fieldKeys.country]
```

However, since the `fieldKeys` record keys are arbitrary strings instead of a well-known set of properties, it allows misuse:

```
// Passes type checker but is a bug.
const bug = d[fieldKeys.doesNotExist]
```

Futhermore, the inferred type of the property when accessed through fieldKeys is a union type of all possible property values of Datum:

```
// Inferred type is 'string | number' instead of string.
const shouldBeString = d[fieldKeys.country]
```

Ideally, TypeScript should infer the keys of the record, but code like this is not allowed since it's recursive:

```
export const fieldKeys: Record<keyof (typeof fieldKeys), keyof Datum> = {
  country: "LOCATION",
  gender: "GENDER"
};
```

I can work around this through boilerplate code like this, but it's not a particularly nice solution:

```
const keyOf = <D, K extends keyof D>(k: K): K => k

export const fieldKeys = {
  country: keyOf<Datum, "LOCATION">("LOCATION"),
  gender: keyOf<Datum, "GENDER">("GENDER")
} as const;
```

In summary, I'd like the following to pass the type checker:

```
type Datum = { LOCATION: string, GENDER: number }

export const fieldKeys = {
  country: "LOCATION",
  gender: "GENDER",

  // Requirement: Type checker complains that NODATUMPROPERTY is is not a property of Datum.
  noDatumProperty: "NODATUMPROPERTY"
};

const d: Datum = { LOCATION: "Germany", GENDER: 1 }

// Requirement: inferred type is 'string'
const country = d[fieldKeys.country]

// Requirement: Type checker complains about non-existing property in fieldKeys.
const bug1 = d[fieldKeys.doesNotExist]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? How are key `country` and a string `LOCATION` connected? Why would it NOT allow arbitrary strings?

Comment: @ritaj I tried to expand the description. Is it clearer now?

Comment: All of those snippets appear to work, so I'm not sure I understand the question: [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsArgWygXigbygGQPIDCAggCoCSeAcgFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gDRQDiAopRh8ASrQYsOUAL4AoGRAAeYAPaNgUAMbLWDKADNmEADYATANIQQdWsIhbGJgDzi2XKAGtLyvbAQoAfOhYMlCayoisTCC0AET4xORUMZwhUOwQrCYQjLH8giIxMlIA3HJaOuomtPBIqBiYqfGkFDRQMTzZyHCsIMmpeUKibV1GEH0lZdq6WhFRQSYA2gbG5pZ0AHQzkYwgALqlMnoRGsDM2vqOJFCKwBkmdFhS-gAUVVAk3MumFlY2dqpOGJbKLJDxeHwkfwASmCoTCOmUo3WRmU7FeS0M3zWm3C2z2UNKskOjhqAVe3AaoSBuJBsSaiUohSkBKAA)

Comment: I updated the description to hopefully make the question clearer.